# Added rep notification isn't going away after clicking it

Tags: bug, reputation, notifications

Edit: This has now been resolved.

Not a major bug, but figured it was worth noting. When I click in the pane that shows added reputation, after exiting the pane the green number showing the added rep goes away... then comes back after I refresh the page. I tried it on three different sites to the same result. The screenshots below are in chronological order - sorry for the lazy formatting, hopefully it's very clear what I'm trying to communicate.

[image: Initially opening the reputation pane]

[image: Closing the reputation panel and the +10 goes away]

[image: Then when I refresh the page it's back again]

Comment: +1, having the same trouble

Comment: Me too, and recently had two upvotes and they are NOT showing up.

Comment: Take into account there is a datacenter transfer in progress, moving services from NYC to Oregon.