# For crying out loud, I've read that message already

Tags: bug, status-norepro, notifications, top-bar

Prior to the recent "read-only" mode related to the [data center migration](https://stackstatus.tumblr.com/post/87327655099/data-center-failover-may-31st-2014), someone commented on an answer of mine.  I did not visit that site prior to the maintenance period, so I never cleared the notification.

When the site came out of read-only mode, I noticed that the inbox notification, which I click and the notification disappeared.

But when I go to another page (or reload the current page), the notification comes back.

Ok, here it is:

[image: "Initial"]

Good it's gone

[image: Yeah, its gone]

Ack, it came back (again and again and again)

[image: It's baacck]

Given the notifications that have come from this question, it might be the top bar that is busted.  I did not see any reputation notifications at all and the inbox nofitications still displays `(1)` despite that fact that this question (as of this writing) has 2 comments.

---

And now the issue with the top-bar (rep notification and the ever present inbox notification appears to be gone.  Given the timing, it may have been related to the migration (either directly or indirectly).

Comment: Related: [Added rep notification isn't going away after clicking it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233447)

Comment: I get that occasionally unrelated to any apparent ongoing maintenance.

Comment: The issue I was having, which Martijn linked to (the new rep notifications was doing exactly the same thing,) has now been resolved. Are you still having problems, @psubsee2003?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for bringing this up. I am unable to reproduce the issue at this time, so I have to conclude that it was an isolated incident related to some factor such as the migration you mentioned earlier. Sorry for the inconvenience.